# node.js and websocket module chat returns no data

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am using the following code https://gist.github.com/2031681 for a simple chat app.

I run `node chat-server.js` and get

```
Tue Jan 08 2013 15:45:52 GMT+0200 (IST) Server is listening on port 1337
```

I try to access it through `http://localhost:1337/chat.html` and get the following

```
No data received
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

I am new to node.js and I have no idea where this problem might be coming from

Comment: `socket.io` with `node.js` is a simpler solution. for an example chat system: http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/ and `socket.io` is easily installed within node: http://socket.io/. I am not saying this is wrong, it's just this is a much simpler way to use sockets and node

Comment: it should be `frontend.html` isn't it?

Comment: @vinayr yes, but it gives me the exact same result

Comment: Do you get some more infos about this issue ? I experienced the same problem but can't find any people who got the same... We ARE using socket.io

Comment: @Sebf yes, take a look at the HTML https://github.com/ilyador/node.js-board-game/tree/master/views and the server.js https://github.com/ilyador/node.js-board-game/blob/master/app.js files

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried this tutorial and faced the same problem. But i have found issues and fixed it.

You have to run chat.html as a file by simply double clicking the file you dont need to access it via localhost. Also change

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it will work. If you want it to be accessible on other computers on your network put it in wamp/www folder or htdocs folder in xampp and change the following line in frontend.js file:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1337');
```

into

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://your_pc_ip:1337');
```

Answer (score 0):

Having search for hours from where a very similar issue can come from, when suddenly we discover that the server with our API and web service was down. The app was running at localhost, but API calls to the server don't return nothing ha-ha :(